# how to get service plan for "DataCache" service?

Tags: ibm-cloud

I would like to know the plan of "DataCache" service before creating an instance from marketplace.

I can see there is a "DataCache" service in marketplace:
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>cf marketplace | findstr Data
- **DataCache**                     free, starter*, standard*, premium*
Improve the performance and user experience of web applications by retrieving information from fast, managed, in-memory caches, instead of relying entirely on slower disk-based databases.
- DataWorks                         free
                             Find, prepare, and deliver data with an intuitive app or with powerful APIs.
- MobileData                        Shared*
                             Enhance your mobile apps through simple to use SDKs to save shared data in a scalable, managed database as a service. Powered by Cloudant.
- XPagesData                        xpages-data-free
                             Create an IBM Notes .NSF database to store your XPages Domino data.
- namara-catalog                    free
                             Open Data. Clean and simple.
- reappt                            reappt:pushtechnology:dif03
                             Real Time Data Distribution Service
- sqldb                             sqldb_small*, sqldb_free, sqldb_premium*
                             SQL Database adds an on-demand relational database to your application. Powered by DB2, it provides a managed database service to handle web and transactional workloads.
- timeseriesdatabase                small*
                             Time Series Database (powered by Informix) is purpose-built for fast and efficient storage and analysis of time series data.

When I try to retrieve detail description of the "DataCache" service, I got the "Could find service" error.
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>cf marketplace -s "**DataCache**"
Getting service plan information for service DataCache as yujames.tw@gmail.com...
FAILED
**Could not find service**

However, I can retrieve detail description for any other service such as "DataWorks":
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>cf marketplace -s "DataWorks"
Getting service plan information for service DataWorks as yujames.tw@gmail.com...
OK

service plan   description                                                 free or paid
free           There is currently no charge for the use of this service.   free

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cf m | grep DataCache
DataCache                         free, starter*, standard*, premium*
```

The plans are free, starter, standard and premium. I agree that getting details for some services does not work using cf - defect. I will raise this issue with the team.

[See plans in the UI](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/data-cache/)

To create it

```
cf cs DataCache free myDataCache
```